# My error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got the problem in my blog. When I use single quote in `textik` this error appear.

> INSERT INTO `clanky` (`nadpis`, `textik`, `datum`, `autor`, `kategorie`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 2

I already know that you cant use single quotes in string due to SQL injection. So im trying to fix it. I tried so many tutorials but nothing helped me.

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST["btn"])) {

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$nadpis = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nadpis']);
$textik = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['textik']);
$datum = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['datum']);
$autor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['autor']);
$kategorie = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['kategorie']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `clanky` (`nadpis`, `textik`, `datum`, `autor`, `kategorie`)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
// '". $_POST['nadpis']."','". $_POST['textik']."','". $_POST['datum']."','". $_POST['autor']."','". $_POST['kategorie']."'
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    echo "SQL error";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiss", $nadpis, $textik, $datum, $autor, $kategorie);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New Record added";
    header("Location: https://www.globalgraphicdesign.eu/welcome.php");
}else {
    echo "Error" . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
$conn->close();
}


?>
```

I should redirect you to welcome page.

Comment: You do not need to escape strings while using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to prepare it, and using `query()`, thereby attempting to execute it twice. It will fail when using `query()`, because placeholders `?` are not allowed there. You should also not escape input when using a prepared statement. You should also not output anything before a `header()` call. You can also enable MySQLi to throw exceptions, which makes error-handling much easier.

Your entire snippet can be reduced to the following.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (isset($_POST["btn"])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `clanky` (`nadpis`, `textik`, `datum`, `autor`, `kategorie`)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST['nadpis'], $_POST['textik'], $_POST['datum'], $_POST['autor'], $_POST['kategorie']);
        $stmt->execute();
        header("Location: https://www.globalgraphicdesign.eu/welcome.php");
        $stmt->close();
        exit;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later";
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help its is working :) God Bless you pal

Comment: Let me suggest you to avoid manual error reporting. It's a different matter that should be defined elsewhere. Please check [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting)